# Best practices in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the best practices we need to follow in developing Angular2 apps using Typescripts.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Best practice on StackOverflow is to not ask opinionated questions ;-)

Comment: Ohh k, I understand. Thanks @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the official [TypeScript coding guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines) from Microsoft.

Comment: No. Just read the first line of the document: _"NOTE: These are Coding Guidelines for TypeScript Contributors."_ It's not a recommendation for TypeScript users.